# Signed APK build failure re:play-services-ads-identifier.properties collision

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am experiencing a build error only during Signed APK build.  Previously Signed APK Builds worked without issue.  Only change since last signed APK Build is I have updated to the new Android Studio 3.6 -Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6200805.

The Build Output is:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   Entry name 'play-services-ads-identifier.properties' collided

build.gradle(:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.clearnetsolutions.qrverify"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'


}
```

build.gradle(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

If I build an unsigned APK:

```
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:multiDexListDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageDebug
> Task :app:assembleDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
24 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 23 up-to-date
```

If I build a signed APK:

```
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:multiDexListDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Entry name 'play-services-ads-identifier.properties' collided

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 982ms
24 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 23 up-to-date
```

I'm not sure how I update or resolve the :app:packageDebug issue? and/or identify the play-services-ads-identifier.properties collision?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I seemed to have resolved the issue by deleting the apk and json files located in the app/debug directory.

After deleting, the signed APK build completed successfully.

Comment: Why does this even happen? I spent 2 days uploading my code to github, then deleting my local files and clone my repo again and again.

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure why this error occurs.  My guess is that there is a mismatch on signatures that occurs whether this is due to trying to generate numerous signed APKs or some expiry factor associated with the debug apk...  BUT oddly enough - this solution was the only way I could proceed.

Comment: Just Clean + rebuild worked fine for me (Build menu + Clean Project). Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Delete all folders in your `app\build\outputs\apk` (Both `debug` and `release`) directory. Then `clean project`, `rebuild project`, and finally `Run` your project. In my case, I was also facing the issue of running APK in the emulator and I resolved it by doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Cleaning the build by going to `Build -> Clean` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I observed the problem with gradle version: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0`

Upgraded the version to `4.1.2` in project level `build.gradle` file as following, and then after running `Build->Clean` generated the apk again without the error(Just clean without version upgrade did not resolve the error in my case):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: Seemingly this fixes the `META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version` error as well